# How to identify per user cost and manage in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am developing a website that uses Azure B2C, Azure Storage (Blobs, Tables, Queues and file share) among others. I want to restrict the user transaction of... say file uploads/Downloads with some giga bytes and then give them a message that their quota is over for this month.
Is this possible for keeping track of individual B2C customer in Azure as a website owner? what's the best approach that is available to handle this?

Thanks in Advance,

- Murthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Azure Storage **don't** have any feature to restrict customer's consumption.

The only way might meet your need is that **using a script**, whatever language azure support.

To be brief, the script's logic could be:

1. Create a table with customers' information.
2. Set the limit of every user. Write the function for automate operating usage and remaining memory, and store the usage field's value and the remaining memory field's value to the table. I use Last to present remaining memory in the table.
3. Compare the file size with the customer's memory remain, when the upload api requested. If the 'Last' memory have 10k more than the file to be uploaded, allow uploading, otherwise, deny the request.
4. If upload succeed, get the file size when customer upload/download file from storage, and stored it in the table.

The table just like this: (Just for example, you should modify with your need)

[image]